# Vertically and horizontally centering HTML5 Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, centering, vertical-alignment

So  I have this and want to center it vertically and horizontally:

```
<div id="hd_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:600px;height:405px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="hd/hd.js?88618"></script>
</div>
```

I have tried every solution and none seem to work for me. Do I need to add something into the js?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to position a script?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa - the script might be `document.write`-ing something.

Comment: its javascript for moving/fading text over a background which is  600 x 405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#hd_type_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    width: whatever;
    height: whatever; 
    margin-left: -whatever_width_is / 2;
    margin-top: -whatever_height_is / 2;
}
```

Remember though that absolute or relatively positioned elements are positioned relative to the "closest" parent container that's also absolute or relatively positioned.

In other words, if your `div` is a child of some other `div` that's absolutely positioned, you won't be centering to the screen, but centering to the parent `div`.

Update: Assuming you are trying to make a popup box of some kind, you might also want an `overflow: hidden` directive too.

Comment: Thanks, but it still wont vertically center. At the moment i have:  
  
  <table height=100% width=100%>
<tr><td valign="middle">
  <center>
 <div style ="margin:auto;width:600px">

Which centers it fine, but vertically even with your code it just wont work. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry I typed margin right instead of margin top, my bad! It works perfectly thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="hd_hype_container" style="margin-top:50%;margin:0 auto;width:600px;height:405px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="hd/hd.js?88618"></script>
</div>
```